# Good info buried because of downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Recently I asked a question that got a lot of downvotes in short amount of time. (The post is now deleted but some of you can still see it I supposed)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700164

There is a good point there that made me decide to delete the question.
It is a feature of the compiler that I don't aware of before. (pretty basic one)

This is how things turn out and I am the only one benefiting something from the question.
I am totally fine with that but do we need everyone to ask a question in order to know the info.

So it will kind of look like this:
- Mr.A ask a question got downvotes and useful info.
- The question Mr.A asked is gone.
- Mr.B ask a question got downvotes and useful info.
- The question Mr.B asked is gone.
- And so on...

Can we do it better or this is how things supposed to be?

Comment: It was useful content, but in your opinion. The downvoters thought otherwise.

Comment: The useful content is in the comment which actually got upvotes

Comment: So this is about a sideways related comment which got 2 upvotes, under an otherwise poorly received self-answered question? I really see nothing of value here that we should desperately preserve. You could choose to undo your deletion if you wish. Because after all you decided to nuke it yourself.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Question wasn't buried, because of the downvote, you just decided to delete the question for a bad reason

Answer (score 5):

A useful comment will never be a reason to undelete a question. You could look around for a question from someone else with a similar lack of knowledge, that you can now answer because of what you've learned.

You may find there are already many questions-and-answers here that contain the same information. Or perhaps just questions, in which case answering them will not only keep the information findable, but will help the asker who didn't know that compiler information. Or you may find that nobody else has ever had that misconception before. In all of these cases, it probably doesn't matter that the useful comment has disappeared.